# Form remote: true authenticity_token disappear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authenticity-token

If I set remote: true to my form authenticity_token disappear.  I have to add authenticity_token: true to my form? What about caching? If I cache the form I have to add authenticity_token: true? Is a problem that authenticity_token is cached? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the [`jquery-rails`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) gem in your app? This'll add the CSRF token to `remote: true` AJAX form submissions automagically:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L69

```js
// Make sure that every Ajax request sends the CSRF token
CSRFProtection: function(xhr) {
  var token = rails.csrfToken();
  if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
}
```